# Metric for target value homogeneity across feature distributions?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, supervised-learning

I want to find a metric that can **quantify target value homogeneity across feature distributions**.

Without any background knowledge, it is hard to describe exactly what I want.

Therefore, I provide **an example for intuition**.

In the following scatter plots,

- *x-axis and y-axis are two reduced dimensions of the original feature vector*
- *color of dots represents the target value (red to violet, from low to high)*

**Example (1): Low homogeneity**

For this plot below, I describe it as **low homogeneity** because obvious clusters corresponding to a specific range of target value **can be easily isolated**.

[image: low]

**Example (2): High homogeneity**

While for the plot below, I describe it as **high homogeneity** because clusters corresponding to a specific range of target value **cannot be easily isolated**.

In other words, the target values are *homogeneously spread on this dimensionally reduced 2D feature plane.*

[image: high]

**So the question is, do we have a metric that can quantify such target value homogeneity?**

p.s. figures were borrowed from https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2022.06.03.494724v2.full#F3

Comment: This is an interesting question and gets a +1 from me, but I am pessimistic. This is basically what regression does (figures out different groups in the features based on the outcome variable, at least sort of), and there is no one way to do regression.